# Non-vulgar way to express that you "f-word love" something

Tags: politeness, synonyms

So I wanted to say that I really love some web service, (I could pretty much say this about stack exchange too!) and I wanted to keep the power of my words, but I have a bad habit of using f-word in english more than I want, since English is not my native tongue and it makes it easier, when you lack rich vocabulary. I heard that usage of f word has a strong connotation and is generally perceived badly. I am not sure how to replace such an expression. There is the "God, I love something something", but I would also like to avoid using the word "God".

There surely are common ways to express such a thing, but I cannot come up with anything. Would you suggest some ways, please?

Comment: Surely you can find some other intensifier: "I absolutely love StackExchange!" or "I really love StackExchange!" Or use a euphemism, like *flipping* or *fracking* or *fricking*.

Comment: Oh wow, zoinks! I really, truly, absolutely _love_ this web service!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace the F-work with another F-word as in "I freaking love this service!". This way use still use the F-word without using the F-word.

In the case of the "God, I love this." You could use also a differnt word, e.g. "Jeez, I love this". See [Jeez](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=jeez).

Or you could simply omit God. "Oh my, this is incredible!".

Comment: (I know this is a lost cause, but...) The word that you, (and Hollywood and the media) have latched onto, "freaking", is a mispronunciation of the word "frigging". Various sources date this euphemism for the f-word to the mid-16th or 17th century. I assume its origin is British, because it still clings to life in this form in the New England States- where the dialect (AmE) changes more slowly.

Comment: I don't see a huge difference between _freaking_ and _fucking_, nor _God_ and _Jeez_ and _Oh my_ just seems to fall short of _Oh my God_. All of them are just minced, not really alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

replacements for 'I f***ing love this'

I totally love this. 
I absolutely love this. 
I truly love this.
I so love this.

replacements for 'God, I love this'

Wow, I love this.
Yeah, I love this.
Cool, I love this. (Slightly more context dependent as cool is descriptive.)

All of the above expressions are colloquial but polite.

Answer (score 0):

What word you're going to use depends on who you are talking to. I wouldn't use the same adverb when giving a lecture, talking to my grandma, explaining something to a judge in court, or chatting with my colleagues at work. I suggest the following:

- **very much**
- **truly**
- **tremendously**
- **immensely**

"freaking" might be considered vulgar at certain places and I would only use it as an intensifier if I were angry. But that's me.